# Editing User Profile w/ Forms Authentication

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

We're using Forms Authentication in SharePoint.  When the account is created, the administrator can add some information, like name and address.  But the required fields are username and email address.

When a user goes to their profile page, all the fields are blank and they are unable to edit them.  I have read a number of articles discussing how to import profiles from another data store, or to sync profiles.  This doesn't work for us, because we don't have another data store where these profiles are stored.

Will I just have to recreate the edit profile page and build a custom profile editor?  Is this information exposed via SharePoint API?  I don't think directly editing the database is a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you log in to the "Shared Services administration" through the "Central Admin Tool" there is an option "Profile services policies". You can define in here what fields are user-overridable.